# Android: asking for Run Time permissions runs first permission request but skips others

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

If I ask for several `permissions` at one time on `Android`, `run time permissions` works great and asks the user for all the permissions I am requesting. That is if I do them all in one call.

If I instead choose to separate `run time permission` requests into groups, so that I first request access to `contacts`, then afterwards request access to `SMS`, my program will ignore the request to `SMS` and will ultimately treat the `SMS` request as rejected. Why is this? does the program proceed through code while waiting for the user to respond? How can I keep my `permission requests` separate and still be able to request permissions right after each other?

The reason why I don't want to do all permissions at once is because I only want ask for permissions when I need them. That is why I have separated permissions into groups.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
Sample code: checkPermissions is called

```
public boolean checkPermissions(int permissionsToCheck)
{
    // Use constants above to specify permissions check to do
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        //Do not need to check the permission
        return true;
    } else {
        switch (permissionsToCheck) {
            case PERMISSIONS_FOR_MESSAGING:
                return ( checkAndRequestContactPermissions() && checkAndRequestSMSPermissions() );
            case PERMISSIONS_FOR_BLUETOOTH:
                return checkAndRequestBluetoothPermissions();
            default:
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Calls `checkAndRequestContactPermissions()` and `checkAndRequestSMSPermissions()`

```
private boolean checkAndRequestContactPermissions() {
    int permissionReadContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    int permissionWriteContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionReadContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    if (permissionWriteContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CONTACTS);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean checkAndRequestSMSPermissions() {
    int permissionReadSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    int permissionSendSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionReadSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    }
    if (permissionSendSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I try to check if I have permissions to Contacts and SMS but it only requests permission to Contacts instead of both.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: "How can I keep my permission requests separate and still be able to request permissions right after each other?" -- this is the opposite of: "The reason why I don't want to do all permissions at once is because I only want ask for permissions when I need them". This is why a [mcve] is important when asking questions about your code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have this one example of needing to ask both permissions at once. But I will also request permission for bluetooth and other things later. Keeping the requests seperate also makes it easier to use the code again in a new project.